# Yii cleaning URLs

Tags: php, yii

I have this url:

```
http://mysite.com/pages/index?slug=how-does-it-work
```

I want to change that url into like this:

```
http://mysite.com/how-does-it-work
```

So as you can see, `page` and `index` has been removed in the url.
Page here is a controller while index is the action of the controller.
This is my code on my Page Controller:

```
public function actionIndex($slug)
{
   if(!empty($slug))
   {
    $pagesInfo = Pages::model()->find(array("condition"=>"slug='$slug'"));
    $isAdmin = 0;
    if(isset(Yii::app()->user->idUser)){
       $isAdmin = Users::model()->findByPk(Yii::app()->user->idUser)->isAdmin;
    }

    if($pagesInfo !== null){
      $this->render('index',array(
        'pagesInfo'=>$pagesInfo,
        'isAdmin'=>$isAdmin,
       ));
    }else{
       throw new CHttpException(404,'Page cannot be found');
    }
   }
}
```

This is also my `.htaccess`

```
IndexIgnore */*
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . index.php
```

I honestly don't know how to transform that URL into my expected URL output. I know That's why I did not post what I did.

Your help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks! :)

Answer (score 2):

You should simply modify your urlManager config, e.g :

```
'urlManager'=>array(
    'urlFormat'=>'path',
    'showScriptName'=>false,
    'rules'=>array(
        '<slug>'=>'page/index',

        // ... other rules
    ),
),
```

http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/topics.url

Answer (score 0):

Did you already change the "urlFormat" to "path" in the config/main.php of your project?

How do you want to invoke this action?

Comment: Elson, what happens when you access the second URL? After the modification, the first one still work?